# Angular: jQuery().dropdown undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am using Angular Bootstrap and rolling this [datetime picker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker), which requires jQuery.  The jQuery library is loading fine, but I get a console error, which is triggered by this line in the datetime picker source:

`(typeof jQuery().dropdown !== 'function')`

I can't find a reference to the `dropdown` function anywhere in the jQuery source, tho.  What am I missing?

Comment: `.dropdown` is part of [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/). Maybe try installing it.

Comment: are you using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/?

Comment: even tho it's not mentioned in the docs, I pulled it in and got the same error